# How to show that a sequence converges in measure

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measure space, and $f_n,f$ measurable, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure, if
$\forall \epsilon >0 \text{ } \mu(\{x :|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon \}) \rightarrow 0$

I want to show that the sequence
$f_n:=n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$, converges in measure to $0$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

But I do not really know how to do that. Below is my approach.

I guess, for $\epsilon >0$, I try to determine the set $\{x :|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon \}$, in my case
$\{x :|n \chi_{[0,1/n]}|>\epsilon \}=[0,\frac{1}{n}]$. Thus  $\mu([0,\frac{1}{n}])=\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Almost right. Minor points: You did not specify w.r.t. which measure $f_n$ is supposed to converege to $0$ in measure. Your equality in the last but one line holds for $n>\epsilon$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you, I did mean the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Just to extend your toolbox. Its not hard to establish that the given sequence converges a.s. to 0 and almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.